# Qual seria uma boa maneira para aplicar os eventos: onMouseOver e onMouseOut, para todas tag img?

Tags: javascript, loop, while, for

Preciso que esta função seja automatizada para que aplique-se a todas imagens constituídas sobre a documento HTML sem execeção alguma

## Código

```js
function aumenta(obj) {
    obj.height = obj.height * 2;
    obj.width = obj.width * 2;
}

function diminui(obj) {
    obj.height = obj.height / 2;
    obj.width = obj.width / 2;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/1.jpg" width="128px" height="128px" onMouseOver="aumenta(this)" onMouseOut="diminui(this)" />

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/2.jpg" width="128px" height="128px" onMouseOver="aumenta(this)" onMouseOut="diminui(this)" />

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/3.jpg" width="128px" height="128px" onMouseOver="aumenta(this)" onMouseOut="diminui(this)" />
```

Ou seja, não quero ficar tendo o trabalho de editar cada tag `img` para passar os parâmetros `onMouseOver="aumenta(this)"` e `onMouseOut="diminui(this)"`.

Ja tentei algo com `loop` mas acho que estou um pouco confuso devido de tanto ficar modificando.

Comment: Todas as suas imagens do seu documento HTML ficam abaixo de algum outro elemento? Em algum local específico? Ou as imagens são espalhadas entre diversos elementos?

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Ficaram definda dentro de um elemento cujo ha um `id` em especial para elas.

Comment: Pode colocar esse trecho de HTML no exemplo? Creio que efetuar um `Event Delegation` seja a melhor solução, visto que os elementos estão todos agrupados em um elemento.

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Bem, agora complico! Pois coloquei aqui o que julgo ser necessário. Adicione um exemplo de modo que ficasse prático para compreensão do real problema que estava enfrentado. A criação toda fica tudo dinâmica, tag `img` e outros demais elementos, acho que se eu fosse postar isso tudo sairia fora do escopo da pergunta e provalmente ganharia alguns downVote. rsrs

Comment: OK, então não posso formular uma resposta com a ideia do `Event Delegation`, mas aqui fica um link para você analisar se esse é o seu caso. https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você está especificando o evento de uma forma [`inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_don't_use_these).

A outra maneira é adicionar um evento através do [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener).

Para isto, você precisa selecionar todos elementos que você quer, iterar em cada um deles, e setar o evento individualmente.

A título de sugestão, você pode adicionar uma classe a cada tag `<img>` e usar o [`document.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) para selecionar todos elementos que contém esta classe.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName('img');

for (var i =0; i<images.length; i++) {
    var image = images[i];
    image.addEventListener('mouseover', aumenta);
    image.addEventListener('mouseout', diminui);
};

function aumenta(e) {
    var obj = e.target;
    obj.height = obj.height * 2;
    obj.width = obj.width * 2;
}

function diminui(e) {
    var obj = e.target;
    obj.height = obj.height / 2;
    obj.width = obj.width / 2;

}
```

```html
<img class='img' src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/1.jpg" width="128px" height="128px"  />

<img class='img' src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/2.jpg" width="128px" height="128px"  />

<img class='img' src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/3.jpg" width="128px" height="128px" />
```

Answer (score 12):

Uma solução usando somente CSS

```css
.aumentaFi:hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.aumentaFi {
  transition: all 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/1.jpg" width="128px" height="128px" class="aumentaFi" />
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/2.jpg" width="128px" height="128px" class="aumentaFi" />
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/3.jpg" width="128px" height="128px" class="aumentaFi" />
```

Answer (score 6):

Solução em Javascript básico, sem jQuery:

```
// Obtenha todos os elementos do tipo <img>
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

// Cicle por todos os elementos obtidos,
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {

    // Adicionando um listener para o evento mouseover,
    elems[i].addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        this.height = 256;
        this.width = 256;
    });

    // e outro para o evento mouseout.
    elems[i].addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        this.height = 128;
        this.width = 128;
    });
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Uma alternativa para atingir todas tags `img` de modo similar a API moderna [adventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener), seria utilizar-se do *evento* [captureEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/captureEvents). Veja:

```js
var figura = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i in figura) {

 var fotos = figura[i];

if (document.layers);
    document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEOVER | Event.MOUSEOUT);
    fotos.onmouseover = aumenta;
    fotos.onmouseout = diminui;
}

function aumenta() {
    this.height = this.height * 2;
    this.width = this.width * 2;
}

function diminui() {
    this.height = this.height / 2;
    this.width = this.width / 2;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/1.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/2.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/3.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>
```

**w3schools** - [Veja este exemplo rodando numa plataforma externa](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD6B42ZU9RCM)

Ja para este outro exemplo a sintaxe utilizada é mais limpa e amplamente compatível com demais navegadores. Confira:

```js
var figura = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for ( var i in figura ) {
 var fotos = figura[i];

fotos.onmouseover = function() {
    this.width = this.width * 2;
    this.height = this.height * 2;
}

fotos.onmouseout = function() {
    this.width = this.width / 2;
    this.height = this.height / 2;
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/1.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/2.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/3.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>
```

**w3schools** - [Este exemplo também esta funcionando on-line](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD6BGKC4FQG2)

*Para os dois Exemplos dados acima dispenso comentários por se torna mais simples sua compreenssão referente as sintaxe usadas neles.*

Outro jeito é inserir em tempo de execução os eventos Javascript no elemento image.

Podemos conseguir isso assim:

```js
var figura = document.getElementsByTagName("img");

for (var i in figura) {
 var foto = figura[i];

var zoom = {
     onMouseOver : "aumenta(this)",
     onMouseOut : "diminui(this)"
}

for (var visualizar in zoom) {
     foto.setAttribute(visualizar, zoom[visualizar]);
    }
}

function aumenta(obj) {
        obj.height = obj.height * 2;
        obj.width = obj.width * 2;
}

function diminui(obj) {
    obj.height = obj.height / 2;
    obj.width = obj.width / 2;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/1.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/2.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/3.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>
```

**w3schools** - [Uma demostração externa deste exemplo](http://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FCKL1C5TR3DT)

Este é um exemplo de como fazer a inclusão do - `onMouseOver` e `onMouseOut` em tempo real.

## Explicação

A parte principal é o `setAttribute()` basicamente alternar o atributo do elemento `img`:

```
for (var visualizar in zoom) {
        foto.setAttribute(visualizar, zoom[visualizar]);
}
```

Para um perfeito funcionamento otimizado criamos um objeto:

```
var zoom = {
        onMouseOver : "aumenta(this)",
        onMouseOut : "diminui(this)"
}
```

Para guardar essas regras - `onMouseOver="aumenta(this)"` e `onMouseOut="diminui(this)"`.

E logo será aplicado sobre as tags `img` quando o carregamento dos elementos forem realizado.

Sobre vários meio aqui apresentado por mim, o mais simples seria usar CSS1 tornando-se "Cross-Browser" acredito eu. Fazemos muito escrevendo pouco. Observe:

```css
    img:hover {
    width: 240px;
    height: 180px;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/1.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/2.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>

<img src="https://sites.google.com/site/mplayerplugin/louvor/3.jpg" width="120px" height="90px"/>
```

**w3schools** - [Adicionei uma amostra deste exemplo aqui!](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FD7OOOTZXZ6W)

**Nota** - No *IE*, deve ser declarado um `<! doctype>` para que o seletor `hover` funcione em outros elementos que não seja o elemento `<a>`.